# List with hex escaped values to readable string in Python

Tags: python, list, escaping, hex, iso-8859-1

I have a list like this:

```
['<option value="284">\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 Historia </option>', '<option value="393">\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 H\xc3\xa4lsa & sk\xc3\xb6nhet </option>']
```

How do I convert this list into a list with elements that are actually readable?

I believe it is in [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the string value using the `.decode()` method; you are looking at [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) data actually:

```
>>> print lst[0].decode('utf8')
<option value="284">     Historia </option>
>>> print lst[1].decode('utf8')
<option value="393">     Hälsa & skönhet </option>
```

The first bytes represent [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) code point U+00a0, a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;` as HTML entity):

```
>>> lst[0].decode('utf8')
u'<option value="284">\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 Historia </option>'
>>> lst[1].decode('utf8')
u'<option value="393">\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 H\xe4lsa & sk\xf6nhet </option>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when trying to utf-8 encode I get this error: print s[1].decode('utf8') UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 20-23: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: What terminal are you using? That's an *encode* error; the decode succeeded but the `print` is failing.

Comment: I'm just running the bash command 'python file.py' under Debian, Python v2.6.

Comment: @OskarEriksson: And what does `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding`  give you? The `print` statement will convert `unicode` data to that encoding. You can explicitly encode to work around that (`print s[1].decode('utf8').encode('latin1')`) but you may want to [configure Debian to support UTF-8](http://fruit.je/utf-8) instead.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I followed that guide but instead chose ISO-5589-1 which is the charset for sv_SE and now your example works. Cheers!

Comment: @OskarEriksson: Note that UTF-8 is still going to be a better choice; UTF-8 can encode ISO-5589-1 (Latin 1) and (much) more; if you end up having to deal with text outside of Latin 1, you want to move to UTF-8 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like UTF-8:

```
>>> s=['<option value="284">\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 Historia </option>', '<option value="393">\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 H\xc3\xa4lsa & sk\xc3\xb6nhet </option>']
>>> for v in s:
...     print v.decode('utf8')
...     
<option value="284">     Historia </option>
<option value="393">     Hälsa & skönhet </option>
```